# UnityのInputSystemで1つのアクションで上下左右キーの同時押しに対応することは可能ですか？

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

メニュー選択などにおける上下左右キーのトリガー判定入力処理をInputSystemで実装しようとしたところ、
右キーを押したまま上キー、下キーを押したまま右キーなどの、同時押しの対応の仕方がよく分かりませんでした。（ビルトインのInputSystemUIInputModuleの挙動も怪しい気がしています。）
下記のようにすれば理想の挙動が得られたのですが、なんだかInputSystemの恩恵を得られていないように思えてきて、1つのアクションで下記のコードと同等の処理は実装可能なのでしょうか？
下記のコードでは、左右と上下でアクションを分けています。

```
if (NavigateX.WasPressedThisFrame() 
    || (Gamepad.current != null && (Gamepad.current.dpad.left.wasPressedThisFrame || Gamepad.current.dpad.right.wasPressedThisFrame)))
{
    var m = NavigateX.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    if (Gamepad.current != null) 
        m.x += Gamepad.current.dpad.x.value;
    // ...
}
if (NavigateY.WasPressedThisFrame()
    || (Gamepad.current != null && (Gamepad.current.dpad.up.wasPressedThisFrame || Gamepad.current.dpad.down.wasPressedThisFrame)))
{
    var m = NavigateY.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    if (Gamepad.current != null)
        m.y += Gamepad.current.dpad.y.value;
    // ...
```

[image]

バージョン：
Unity: 2021.3.27
InputSystem: 1.6.3